# Read user input as an existing member of a custom class C#?

Tags: c#, class

I'm new to C#, and I am wondering if this is possible.

If I have already initialized an object from a custom class, is it possible to read the user input as the pre-defined object and get a property?

For example, I have an *Animal* class with a set of pre-initialized animals. Each of the animals has a *height* property. I want to find the height of one of the animals based on user input.

So if the user inputs "dog1" into the console, the program prints the height of *dog1* by accessing *dog1.Height*.

If not possible, is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: You can use the Console.ReadLine method to get the string that the user has input, after that you can search in the list using LINQ to find an item that matches the animal name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of set you manage, this is a simple example of the implementation you're describing using a dictionary.

Let's say you have this Animal class:

```
class Animal
{
    public Animal(int height)
    {
        Height = height;
    }

    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

And this kind of set just to simplify it:

```
Dictionary<string, Animal> animals = new Dictionary<string, Animal>();
animals.Add("dog1", new Animal(60));
animals.Add("dog2", new Animal(75));
animals.Add("dog3", new Animal(58));
```

Then you could have a method like this to return the animal's height:

```
public int GetHeight(string userInput)
{
    return animals[userInput].Height;
}
```

Hope it helps!